# Eclipse Plugin To Read Breakpoint Information

Tags: c, eclipse, embedded, eclipse-plugin

I'm working with a legacy embedded debugging tool and it's frustrating to work with.  I just found out however that it can be automated in many ways, such at setting breakpoints on start up.

Since I use eclipse cdt as my development environment, I was wondering if I could write an eclipse plugin that reads all my breakpoints so I can generate a script in my debugging tools proprietary language and then launch the debugger.  This way I can set breakpoints in eclipse and have them load up in my debugger when ever I need them.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click in the breakpoint view and select "Export breakpoints..."

Comment: Is there a way I can automate this?  I'd like to be able to click a button, and Export Breakpoints, then parse and convert to my desired format in one step.

Comment: Well, the menu item is a button. If you want it at your fingertips, just add a keyboard shortcut or use Ctrl+3. If you want automatic conversion, wrap your legacy tool in a startup script which does the conversion before it starts the debugger.